# CSS not saving in Live Server (VS CODE)

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-code

I started learning VS Code through Udemy and I already have one problem that I can't find answer anywhere. In the project I have index.html, style.css and script.js. Now when I try to save the html, the page reloads and everything from the html is applied, the same with javascript, but when I try to save the CSS, the page reloads but everything from the CSS is not applied to the page.

How can I fix this?

Comment: When asking a question, people will be better able to provide help if you provide code that they can easily understand and use to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

First try to add internal CSS then it works check that you correctly linked your style.css and js to index.html.if you provide a screen shot of your vs code i think it's better and easy to give a solution because when linking to html you need to mention correctly file paths.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to programming and I don't know how to link css and html, can you please tell me.

Comment: @DaniloSekulic Sure ```<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<style>``` or it's not worked you have to mention file path before style.css in src=""

Answer (score -3):

Make sure that your style.css is linked correctly to your html page.
Then clear the cache of your browser when you reload.
On chrome => ctrl + f5